# How to get the text of multiple elements split by delimiter using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, delimiter

I am using jQuery to get the text value of multiple `td` elements in a row:

```
var getText = $(this).closest("tr").text();
```

The value of `getText` ends up being one long concatenated string of the text of each element with no breaks. Is it possible to add a delimiter for each new `td` element that it gets the text value from?

Comment: Are you looping through the elements ? how ? what you need to do with that var ? please include more code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd first suggest retrieving an Array of the cells' text, rather than a single String:

```
var cellTexts = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').map(function(){
                  return $(this).text();
                }).get();
```

If you wish to have a single string, with a custom delimiter, you can then call `Array.prototype.join()`, and specify the delimiter you wish to use, for example a comma:

```
var cellTexts = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').map(function(){
                  return $(this).text();
                }).get(),
    allText = cellTexts.join(',');
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).